# Django-mptt form "Attribute error"

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-mptt

I created a class as described in the mptt docs

```
class Locations(MPTTModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

I'm doing a form as written in the manual

```
class RealtyAdminModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    location = TreeNodeChoiceField(queryset=Locations.tree.all(),
                                   level_indicator=u'+--')
class Meta:
    model = Realty
```

But django gives the following error:
`type object 'Locations' has no attribute 'tree'`

Why is this so?

Comment: Maybe as you added a __related_name = 'children'__ you have to use __Locations.children.all()__ instead of __Locations.tree.all()__ ? I'm not sure, but the __tree__ keyword could be a replacement for Django's default __fkname_set__ ?

Comment: I second Locations.children.all()

Comment: I just ran into this error upgrading an old project.  At one time the 'tree' attribute worked, but has since been replaced with objects.all()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why in docs (http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/forms.html) "tree", but the right is "objects":

```
class RealtyAdminModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    location = TreeNodeChoiceField(queryset=Locations.objects.all(),
                                   level_indicator=u'+--')
class Meta:
    model = Realty
```